# Don't understand why object is bouncing off the wall / Pygame

Tags: python, object, pygame

So I was trying to do the DVD bounce on pygame and couldn't get it to hit the walls and bounce off but I eventually found someones elses method and used it but I can't figure out why it actually works , i don't understand why the DVD logo actually bounces off. If someone could help that would be very much appreciated.

```
import pygame
import os


os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Pythonscript\\DVD")

pygame.init()


def gameloop():

    width = 600
    height = 500
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('DVD')
    black = (0,0,0)
    dvd_logo = pygame.image.load("DVD Red.png")
    rect = dvd_logo.get_rect()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()                             
    game = False
    move_speed = [2, 2]

    while not game:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            game= True

            if rect.left < 0:
                move_speed[0] = -move_speed[0]
                dvd_logo = pygame.image.load("DVD Pink.png")
            if rect.right > width:
                move_speed[0] = -move_speed[0]
                dvd_logo = pygame.image.load("DVD Blue.png")
            if rect.top < 0:
                move_speed[1] = -move_speed[1]
                dvd_logo = pygame.image.load("DVD Yellow.png")
            if rect.bottom > height:
                move_speed[1] = -move_speed[1]
                dvd_logo = pygame.image.load("DVD Red.png")

            rect.left += move_speed[0]
            rect.top += move_speed[1]       
            screen.fill(black)
            screen.blit(dvd_logo, rect)
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)


gameloop()      
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: What confuses you about the `if` statements? Which one in particular do you mean?

Comment: They do the same as they always do - if the condition is true, the code below is executed, otherwise it isn't. Do you not understand what `rect` or `rect.left` or `rect.right` is? What `<` and `>` are doing? What `[0]` means?

Answer (score 1):

So the `rect` object represents the position and size of the `dvd_logo` image. In each frame, the code checks if the `left` of `rect` is less than zero (left edge of window), if `right` is greater than `width` (right edge of window), if `top` is less than zero (top edge of window), or `bottom` is greater than `height` (bottom edge of window). If the `left` or `right` are beyond the left or right edges, the `move_speed[0]` (left/right speed) is negated, and the same is true for `top`/`bottom` with `move_speed[1]`.

If your move_speed[0] is -2 (moving left) and `rect.left` is less than zero, `move_speed[0]` becomes `2`, so it'll move right instead of left. Again, same concept for top/bottom and move_speed[1].